# Request for ?per_page= didn't working properly in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, vuejs2, wordpress-rest-api

I've a problem with WordPress REST API request.
And the problem is when I'm request a data using url below

```
www.example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=2
```

The json keep returning all the posts and ignored the endpoint
I hope I could have an answer for this problem
Here is the specification:

```
wordpress Version = WordPress 5.1.3
PHP Version = PHP/5.4.16
Server = nginx/1.12.2
```

Comment: This is to function normally. check to see if any plugins or your theme are modifying it. Try disabling them to test

Comment: Hello, thanks for the comment but I only activating 2 plugins and that plugins is Classic Editor and Health Check & Troubleshooting, for the theme I tried to use default theme but only it doesn't effective yet to solve the problem

Comment: Update your WordPress to the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `per_page` and `offset` together.

For instance:

```
https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2?per_page=5&offset=5
```